# I am unable to relate the given data with the asked questions.i dont know how to find out the centres of the circles using the given data

Tags: circles

The radius of the two circles are 5 unit respectively. The contact point between two circles is (1,2).the external general tangent equation between the two circle is 4x+3y=10.plz help me to find out the equations of the two circles??
I have just find out the slope of the equation.I really expect ur help cause I am a beginner.
In this question I have added the radius of the circles.**strong text**

Comment: Ignore the equations and coordinates. You have two congruent circles, the point at which they touch, and a common external tangent. Draw a picture of that. Can you see how to get the radius of the circles from the picture? If so, then go back and see if you can calculate the radius from the equations and coordinates you are given.

Comment: Ah, I see that [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2908899/409) is identical to this one. Re-posting is not the way to call attention to your question. I'm voting to close.

Comment: I m sry if my question is not so acceptable. Plz accept my apology. But in the previous question I forgot to add some data like the radius of the circles. So its not actually duplicate but an edited version of the previous question. Plz forgive me if I did something against the terms and conditions.

Comment: Don't feel bad. It's not a crime. :)  Editing your previous question with the missing information was the correct course of action. Since the two questions are now identical, though, you should consider deleting this one.

Answer (score 0):

The line between circle centers has a slope of $3/4$ (the negative reciprocal of the tangent equation) and also passes through point $(1, 2)$. The two circle centers are therefore located at $(1+4, 2+3)$ and $(1-4, 2-3)$ which are $(5, 5)$ and $(-3, -1)$

From the circle center locations and radius, you can determine the equations of the circles using $(x – h)^2 + (y – k)^2 = r^2$

[image]

Comment: Sir thank u soo much.I have clearly understood the solution now.my doubts r clear.